# IE 8 Zip file download problem from Apache Web server (Downloads corrupted files)

Tags: apache, internet-explorer-8, download

I have a zip file containing pdf, .exe inside. When I am using FF or Chrome to download it, it works fine even if I stopped for few seconds before clicking save or open button on popped up dialog box. But when I use IE 8 and do not press the save or open button immediately, it is still able to download the files but a corrupt one. The original file size is 15 MB and the corrupt download would be like 848K or 880K etc. Files are hosted in Apache HTTPD web server on server machine. Is there anything I can do with httpd.config or IE to solve this problem?

Comment: Please, someone on stackoverflow suggest me a solution. I have always found solution to my problems related to programming. Any help will be highly appreciated !

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I posted this question on Stack Overflow, I was expecting a reply soon but any ways I have found the answer to the problem. The way IE works is very different than Mozilla Firefox and Chrome. Once you click a link to download something, you are asked by the browser to save, open or Cancel. Mozilla and Chrome being the smart guys, start downloading the files at your click to the download link before you hit save, open or cancel and deletes the downloaded file if you hit cancel. But IE has a different story. Once you hit download link, it will wait for the user to respond to the popup box with open, save or cancel to start downloading the file. In my case, our organization had a global config file for the Apache HTTPD server serving the content with Timeout=3. So if the user clicked the save or open in 3 seconds, they are good to go or they received a truncated/corrupted zip file. So if you are facing such issue with IE, check your Timeout in httpd.config file to check the parameters locally and globally. Also check your proxy server settings because a proxy might be the culprit too.

Comment: Please add/update the content if you have more details about the problem!